# Get the Dayname of string date js

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to javascript I am trying to get the name of my date string 
formatted dd/MM/yyyy

ex:

```
23/02/2019
expected output: Saturday
```

my code giving Nan. I will really appreciate any advice or help. Thank you

```
var ot="23/02/2019";
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var d = new Date(ot);
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
  console.log(dayName);
```

Comment: Try `console.log(new Date("23/02/2019"))`.  You'll see it's an invalid date (the string format is not recognised).  Use Japanese date format (YYYY/MM/DD) and it will work -> `console.log(new Date("2019/02/23"))`

Comment: Where do you get the date string from?  If you could change that to give you the date in that format (previous comment) then your code would work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `new Date(ot)` might be failing because of timezone issues. For safer side, you can break down your date string and pass it to `new Date()` as year, month, date.

> JS months are index based so `-1` from month in string

```js
var ot="23/02/2019";
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var otArr = ot.split('/')
var d = new Date(otArr[2], otArr[1] - 1, otArr[0]);
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
console.log(dayName);
```

Answer (score -2):

Format to get a new date object with year , month and date is `new Date(year,month,date);`

To extract them seperately from the string date formatted (date/month/year) we need to split them by slash and provide the required parameters to the function as shown below.

```js
var ot="23/02/2019";
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var splits = ot.split('/');
// var d = new Date(ot.split('/')[2],ot.split('/')[1] -1 ,ot.split('/')[0]);
var d = new Date(splits[2],splits[1] -1 ,splits[0]);
var dayName = days[d.getDay()];
console.log(dayName);
```

Comment: the month is at index 1 , the year is at index 2 & the date is at index 0. look closely

Comment: This is wrong.  Months in Javascript are zero indexed (0 == January) so this returns the day of 23rd March.  Also, don't repeat the split.  Store it as an array -> `var otSplit = ot.split("/");`

Comment: there is no harm in splitting repeatedly.

Comment: I did not say it was harmful.  It's a terrible habit and should be nipped in the bud.

Comment: Your variable d is `Sat Mar 23 2019` and not `Sat Feb 23 2019`. This is because > JS months are index based so you need to substract 1 from month.

Comment: thanks for letting me know that ashish , i learned something new. answer updated